# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' Login setup in SSMS

Tags: entity-framework-5, ssms

I know there are a myriad of similar questions but none of them deal with the case where the user is set up in SSMS.

I am using EF5 and am trying to move from the `LocalDb\v11.0` default to `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

My connection strings are:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=asdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.asdf.csdl|res://*/Models.asdf.ssdl|res://*/Models.asdf.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=asdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I load the site, I get `Cannot open database "asdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.`

The user `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` is set up as owner of the database in SSMS.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix in the end - just remove `User Instance=True;` from the query strings.